# Storing Data From a Website to A Server (FTP)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, sql-server-2008

I am Using the Following:

- ASP.NET
- WCF

I want to Know how to Store the Data Im Getting from the Website to my FTP server?
If anyone knows could they please Provide Code Snippets for Examples or usage thereof?
I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: What data are you getting? From where do you get it? Do you know that web requests can be used for FTP?

Comment: I'm getting different types of data from a website (strings, integers etc). Im very unfamiliar to the topic which is why i ask.